# Do astronauts play reduced gravity sports when folks on Earth aren't watching? Ever quasi-regularly? If so, what sports?

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle, reduced-gravity-sports

Astronauts on space stations routinely do things for their own entertainment and also things for public outreach/entertainment of folks on Earth.

Videos below are examples.

But I'm curious about any evidence of *reduced gravity sports in earnest*.

**Question:** Do astronauts play reduced gravity sports when folks on Earth aren't watching? For reasons other than making occasional videos for public outreach? For example, for the pure fun of it or for the exercise or both? Has it ever become a quasi-regular thing?

If so, *what sports?*

**note:** All space stations and crewed and uncrewed spaceflight missions are on the table here.

---

First video is **mostly loud music** on audio, but between roughly `06:45` and `08:45` there is ambient sound and and explanation of No-Handball:

Comment: This year the three astronauts aboard Tiangong are [likely quite busy setting up shop](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54590/12102) but had time to comment about the olympics. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZMS1efbCvM In four years Tiangong will likely be better established much larger and there may be more time for sports.

Comment: Ambiguity in the opening paragraphs: Is "for real" defined as "do things their own entertainment", or is "for own entertainment" *excluded* from "for real". In any case, this could use a definition of what you consider "real".

Comment: I wonder how No-Handball is different from No-Football (No-Soccer for our Non-ESA friends)

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys for real means "other than for occasional videos for public outreach". It's right there within the same sentence.

Comment: “other than occasional videos for public outreach" is still very broad and open to interpretation.  Please consider narrowing the scope of your question to specific purpose or application.

Comment: @Paul I don't know about "specific purpose or application" (I'm not filing a patent here) but I understand now there's need to adjust the wording. While I'm not sure it would make a good title, "Have astronauts ever engaged in reduced gravity sports regularly, when folks on Earth aren't watching?" might be another way to ask this.

Comment: @Paul since there's been no further comments I've gone ahead and made that change.

Comment: I saw a video once of two astronauts throwing playing cards at a container, does that count as a "sport"? It was quite amusing to see a gently thrown card spinning across the 'room' in a flat arc, taking a good 20 second to cross to the target.

Comment: "...when folks on Earth aren't watching...", but Big Brother is always watching those on the ISS. I haven't decided if that's [Orwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orwellian) or more like the [Truman Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show).

Comment: @Fred [What's this dark, ceiling-mounted hemisphere in Tianhe module of Tiangong space station? Any counterpart on the ISS and if so what does it look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53984/12102)