# Cartoon-like characters on the side of the Tianwen-1 Mars lander?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art, china, tianwen-1, cnsa

Scott Manley's *excellent* new video [China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY) is chock-full of space-sleuthing goodies and interesting information about the mission, its spacecraft, and some of its engineers.

Below is a screenshot of the [Tianwen-1 lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianwen-1). While the context is the speculation that post-landing remaining fuel was spent by actually firing thrusters on each side resulting in the dipolar bright spots seen from orbit, I noticed that next to the Chinese flag there are some cartoon-like characters.

**Question:** Who are these cartoon-like characters displayed on the side of the Tianwen-1 lander?

---

Screenshots (some cropped, sharpened and otherwise "enhanced" unscientifically) from the video:

[image: Screenshots (some cropped, sharpened and otherwise "enhanced" unscientifically) from Scott Manley's video China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY] [image: Screenshots (some cropped, sharpened and otherwise "enhanced" unscientifically) from Scott Manley's video China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY]

[image: Screenshots (some cropped, sharpened and otherwise "enhanced" unscientifically) from Scott Manley's video China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY]

Comment: Well, .. it's definitely ***not*** [Winnie the Pooh](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/aug/07/china-bans-winnie-the-pooh-film-to-stop-comparisons-to-president-xi)

Comment: @Fred well my first thought was about the [Soviet Winnie the Pooh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh#Soviet_adaptation). That one seems to have even less resemblance of the Chinese president.

Comment: @Ruslan: *Thanks*! ;-)  I never knew there was a Soviet [Pooh Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh). Despite the lack of resemblance to the Chinese president I don't think the Soviet Winnie would be any more acceptable - guilt by name association.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The cartoon characters are the [mascots for the 2022 Winter Olympic games & the Winter Para Olympic games](https://olympics.com/en/news/beijing-2022-officially-launches-olympic-mascot).

The panda figure on the left is for the Olympic Games and the red figure of the right is for the Para Olympic Games.

[image]

Comment: Which leads to the question, why is a Mars lander sporting the image of the 2022 Winter Olympics mascots? Seems kind of obscure for an advertisement.

Comment: @SethR: It could be another display of national pride.

Comment: @SethR Olympic references in space contained in https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54591